# VFP Macro ability in MS SQL

Tags: .net, sql-server, macros, visual-foxpro

I have a task, I don't know how to call it... anyway,

I need to do a report for multiple people with different setup and I was thinking which of which is the best way to do it. Im using **MsSQL** to load the data and some stored procedure to extract and create an export file.

To illustrate,

```
MGR1  ->wants net sales, tax, discount
MGR2  ->wants net sales, gross sales, adjustments, tax
ACCT1 ->wants tax, discounts
```

I was trying to make things dynamic as it can be and to be able to address future requirements if ever... which eventually is inevitable.

Here's what I'm planning,

```
1. I will create 2 table reference:
   a: Table1 stores all the fields required for all personnel (the table will grow in columns)
   b. Table2 stores all the formula for each personnel for each field (the table will grow in rows)
```

I want to know if this is the correct way of doing things, why Im trying to this is because some of the requirements is yet unknown but in a sense I already have all what I need its just I am trying to eliminate the process of going through the scripts everytime there is a change in requirement instead just change the values (formulas) on the table.

Basically, can this be done? what are the pros and cons, and what possible design can be implemented to support the requirements?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I would consider using a reporting tool to do this for you. Tools like SSRS, Business Objects etc. let users specify their own reports and export the results as they want. I know it's potentially a lot of work, but in the long term it may be easier than building your own solution.

Comment: If you're doing this in a VFP application, consider using Stonefield Query: http://stonefieldquery.com/

Comment: @Pondlife, SSRS is not a viable solution for the time being as this reports should be autogenerated at the start of day.

Comment: Is there not a better way to do this, its like a matrix anyway?

Comment: SSRS allows [scheduling reports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx), as do all other 'major' reporting tools so I'm not sure why that should be an issue